# Lots of processes going on of the same "DownloadAD (32 bits)"

Tags: windows-8, process, task-manager

When I open up task manager it is always a lot of processes with the label "DownloadAD (32 bits)". I know it is HPs own software for finger print logins and stuff so I need the Program.

I can remove them one by one but they keep coming up all the time and it is time consuming to do so.

[image]

Comment: Remove the HP software/driver and install it again. Does this fixes it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HPs own software "SimplePass" creates an process called "DownloadAD" every time I used the fingerprint scanner to log into the computer. I thought I needed SimplePass to log in, but I uninstalled it and Windows 8 seemed to work without it.

Simplepass could be used to start programs with different fingers, but I never used it anyway. New drivers would solve the issue.

After uninstalling, the processes disappeared.